# Compare empty string inside if in bash (C style vs Bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I was learning bash when I stuck comparing strings inside if statement.

Script: *shiftDemo.sh*

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 #using shift keyword to shift CLA 
  4 
  5 while true
  6 do
  7         if [ "$1" = "" ]     #change this statement wrt below cases
  8         then
  9                 exit
 10         fi
 11         echo '$1 is now ' "$1"
 12         shift
 13 done
```

I used the following methods:

1.if (( "$1" = "" ))

2.if [ "$1" = "" ]

**Observations:**

1a) `$ bash shiftDemo.sh first second third`

```
`shiftDemo.sh: line 7: ((: =  : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=  ")`
```

1b) `$ sh shiftDemo.sh first second third`

```
shiftDemo.sh: 7: shiftDemo.sh: first: not found
$1 is now  first
shiftDemo.sh: 7: shiftDemo.sh: second: not found
$1 is now  second
shiftDemo.sh: 7: shiftDemo.sh: third: not found
$1 is now  third
shiftDemo.sh: 7: shiftDemo.sh: : Permission denied
$1 is now  
shiftDemo.sh: 12: shift: can't shift that many
```

2)In this case, if statement runs fine with **both the shells** & gives correct output.

```
$ bash shiftDemo.sh first second third
$1 is now  first
$1 is now  second
$1 is now  third

$ sh shiftDemo.sh first second third
$1 is now  first
$1 is now  second
$1 is now  third
```

Based on the above observations, my doubts are:

1. What is wrong with case 1. How can I correct it (I want to use C style syntax throughout my script).
2. Which syntax is preferred so that it will work with both sh & bash shell ?

Comment: Duplicate of [**Test for non-zero length string in bash: \[ -n “$var” \] or \[ “$var” \]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869072/test-for-non-zero-length-string-in-bash-n-var-or-var?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [**Null & empty string comparision in Unix Bash Shell Script**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407235/null-empty-string-comparision-in-unix-bash-shell-script)

Comment: Please do not try to use C-style syntax in shell scripts -- they're very different languages, and you're just going to keep running into problems if you try to write C in shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, the `(( ... ))` notation is dedicated to arithmetic evaluation (see the ARITHMETIC EVALUATION section of the man page). When executing:

```
if (( "$1" = "" ))
```

for the first time, you try to assign variable `first` with nothing instead of the expected integer value, just like if you were executing:

```
if (( first = ))
```

which does not make sense, thus the error message. So, to test if a bash variable is assigned a value different from the empty string, you can use the `test` external command, that is, your `[ ... ]` notation. Type `man test` to see what `test` can do. You can use any of:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
if test -z "$1"
if [ "$1" = "" ]
if test "$1" = ""
if [ "X${1}X" = "XX" ]
if test "X${1}X" = "XX"
...
```

It is difficult to tell what `(( ... ))` does with your `sh`: on most systems, `sh` is not the original Bourne Shell any more. It is sometimes `bash` (that behaves differently when invoked as `sh`), or `dash`, or something else. You should thus first check what `sh` is on your system.

Anyway, if `test` is also an external command of your `sh` (whatever your `sh` is), the best is to use it: by construction, it will behave the same. The only potential difference will be the syntax of the `if` control structure.